# How to update solpg programs

Tags: anchor, solana-program

im normally using https://beta.solpg.io/ for creating and updating my programs. Im also using anchor framework.

When i using devnet i publish and launch my projects simply and i can easily update my programs.

When i share my program on mainnet update button isn't enabled? is anyone know the reason.

My program is upgradeable but upgrade button not activated?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason why it would not work.

You can trigger the upgrade also by typing

```
deploy
```

in the terminal on the bottom. Maybe its just the ui.
Maybe you also need to run

```
build
```

first.
Make sure that when you look at your program in
explorer.solana.com
than in the update authority field is the pubkey that you can see in playground at the bottom.
Like here for example:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/Ewo88GwCAwnUgJty4BRCHr6J3CbWd7G7jFV8moeTprCL?cluster=devnet

Also make sure that when you use playground that you save your keypair and seedphrase of your browser wallet since if you switch browser or clear the cache you could loose it.